# How can I programmaticatly check if a source is in sources.list?

Tags: apt

For both 10.04 LTS and 12.04 LTS, is there a way check to see if a source is in /etc/apt/sources.list from a bash script, other than using grep?

Comment: Why is grep out of the question? Does this repo you are looking for have a unique package? If so you could do "apt-cache search mypackage".

Comment: I don't mind using grep. I am relatively new to being an admin on an Ubuntu box (much more used to how Slackware does things) and I wanted to make sure there wasn't something within the apt/dpkg suite of tools that would be better suited. The "apt-cache search" may work for one repo, but I don't think it will for the other one.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think there is any built-in mechanism to list/check what repos are configured. One thing to point out, you should always create a new repo.list file for any extra repos in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, instead of putting them directly to /etc/apt/sources.list. It is a little safer, and makes it much neater. Maybe that could also be how you check for them to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using `grep` to check the `sources.list` and also checking in `sources.list.d`for the presence of a `foo.list`.

While not as clean of a solution as I had hoped for, it does the job well enough for what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

`apt-cache policy` shows all available sources. Example output (trimmed):

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-lekensteyn-wacom-tablet,a=precise,n=precise,l=Wacom Tablet Drivers,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-lekensteyn-wacom-tablet,a=precise,n=precise,l=Wacom Tablet Drivers,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/testing/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-bumblebee-testing,a=precise,n=precise,l=Bumblebee Developer releases,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/testing/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=LP-PPA-bumblebee-testing,a=precise,n=precise,l=Bumblebee Developer releases,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Canonical,a=precise,n=precise,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
...
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main Translation-nl
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main Translation-en
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.04,o=Ubuntu,a=precise,n=precise,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin nl.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages
```

Using `awk` to retrieve the actual source (URL or file):

```
$ apt-cache policy | awk '/^ *[0-9]/{print $2 " " $3}'
/var/lib/dpkg/status 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/ precise/main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/ precise/main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/testing/ubuntu/ precise/main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/testing/ubuntu/ precise/main
...
http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe
http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/restricted
http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main
```